# I can't get objects of related entity in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I use Symfony 3.2. I have two related entities:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8mb4"}, indexes={ @Index(name="idx_email", columns={"email"}) })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Пользователь с данным email'ом существует.", groups={"Registration"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\VisitedPage", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $visitedPages;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->visitedPages = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function addVisitedPage(VisitedPage $visitedPage)
    {
        $this->visitedPages[] = $visitedPage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove visitedPage
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\VisitedPage $visitedPage
     */
    public function removeVisitedPage(\AppBundle\Entity\VisitedPage $visitedPage)
    {
        $this->visitedPages->removeElement($visitedPage);
    }

    /**
     * Get visitedPages
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getVisitedPages()
    {
        return $this->visitedPages;
    }
}

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * VisitedPage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="visited_page")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VisitedPageRepository")
 */
class VisitedPage
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="visitedPages")
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="page", type="text")
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return VisitedPage
     */
    public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set page
     *
     * @param string $page
     *
     * @return VisitedPage
     */
    public function setPage($page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPage()
    {
        return $this->page;
    }
}
```

When i try call VisitedPage::getUser() (i mean $visitedPage->getUser()) i get object type of user.
But when i call method User::getVisitedPages() i get null.

Method User::addVisitedPage($page) works and relations are saved.
How can i decide this problem?

//Some text to pass validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by running this command - `bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

Answer (score 0):

When you add Visited Page from user try this:

```
class User
{
    //......
    public function addVisitedPage(VisitedPage $visitedPage)
    {
        $visitedPage->setUser($this);
        $this->visitedPages->add($visitedPage);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

also I think you will need to add `cascade={"persist"}` to your `private $visitedPages;` inside of User object:

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\VisitedPage", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $visitedPages;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Relations between entities already save.

Answer (score 0):

You should run

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

or

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

depending upon env you are working